# making the edge of the scrollview fade when scrolling in android

Tags: android, scrollview, fade

I have a `ScrollView` with an image in it.

I want the edges of the `ScrollView` to make a fade effect when I scroll the image.
I'm not talking about the effect you get when you get to the end of the scroll. I want the fade to always exist.

That's what i did (not doing any effect):

```
<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.84"
    android:background="@drawable/screen_nespresso"
    android:fadingEdge="horizontal"
    android:fadingEdgeLength="@dimen/padding_large"
    android:fillViewport="false"
    android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawVerticalTrack="true"
    android:visibility="visible" >
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 121, accepted):

Here is what worked for me:

```
<ScrollView
    android:requiresFadingEdge="vertical"
    android:fadingEdgeLength="150dp">
```

Or instead in your code, you could do the following:

```
ScrollView scroll = findById(...);
scroll.setVerticalFadingEdgeEnabled(true);
// Or `scroll.setHorizontalFadingEdgeEnabled(true)`.
scroll.setFadingEdgeLength(150);
```

Comment: For some more detail: This works in API level 14 and higher. See http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#fadingEdge. That page also recommends avoiding the fading edge for performance reasons.

Comment: Really glad this was implemented into the view. Makes life much easier.

Comment: can we change the fading color? It's white.

Comment: Also in case anyone wondering if this can be done on a recyclerview:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33720836/horizontal-recyclerview-with-fading-edges

The key attribute here is: `android:requiresFadingEdge="horizontal|vertical"`

Answer (score 7):

this is for horizontal:

```
<HorizontalScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scroll"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:requiresFadingEdge="horizontal"
    android:fadingEdgeLength="80dp">
```

Comment: For those like me who aren't 100% on reading XML, the key attributes to look at here are `android:requiresFadingEdge` and `android:fadingEdgeLength`.

Answer (score 4):

Just add these 3 line of code in scroll view and it will look awesome!

```
 android:fadingEdgeLength="80dp"
 android:overScrollMode="never"
 android:requiresFadingEdge="vertical"
```

Answer (score 3):

Add these lines in your ScrollView xml code.

```
<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fadeScrollbars="true"
    android:requiresFadingEdge="vertical"
    android:fadingEdgeLength="50dp">
```