# Google Glass Time

Tags: time, google-glass

Is there a way to get the time in Google Glass pro grammatically? I am using System.currentTimeMillis(); but it gives me a really long number such as: 1403101657961. I want the actual time that the user is looking at when he turns on Glass. Thanks.

Comment: I presume that the time it returned is in seconds. Convert seconds into the date time.

Comment: It is universal time, so its 10:30 now, but in California it is 8:30, there is no way to tell from just 1 number.

Comment: The time returned by `Systme.currentTimeMillis()` is milliseconds passed since Unix Epoch in UTC.

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is create a `Date` object like so:

```
Date dt = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis());
```

If you want it as a formatted string you can take a look at `SimpleDateFormat`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the class [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) to format your time to Date.

Create a date with your millisec :

> `Date date= new Date(System.currentTimeMillis());`

then format it with SDF

> `new SimpleDateFormat(""yyyy.MM.dd G 'at' HH:mm:ss z").format(date)`