# How to fade end of HorizontalScrollView?

Tags: android, material-design, horizontalscrollview

I have a `HorizontalScrollView` wrapped around a `TabLayout` and works great, but it's hard for the use to know that it is actually a horizontal scroll.

How can I fade the end and maybe place an arrow at the end to give the user enough indication that it scrolls?

[image]

```
    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scrollbars="none"
        android:fillViewport="true">
        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </HorizontalScrollView>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [making the edge of the scrollview fade when scrolling in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11538873/making-the-edge-of-the-scrollview-fade-when-scrolling-in-android)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hey i do not have proper idea for your question but here is a similar question .
Check it out.

[making the edge of the scrollview fade when scrolling in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11538873/making-the-edge-of-the-scrollview-fade-when-scrolling-in-android)

Answer (score 2):

This would make left and right edges have fading look:

```
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:requiresFadingEdge="horizontal"
            android:fadingEdgeLength="80dp">
```

Answer (score 2):

Just add in HorizontalScrollView

```
android:requiresFadingEdge="horizontal|vertical" 
android:fadingEdgeLength="10dp"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by overlaying a translucent ImageView, and only showing it when not fully scrolled over.