# Horizontal recyclerview with fading edges

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

If I look at the stackoverflow app's horizontal recyclerview, I can see that they use the "fading edge" technique so that the user will know that there are items on the left and right of the recyclerview and he / she can scroll.

[image: stackoverflow]

In listview, I think this effect is enabled by calling the below as described by Romain Guy (http://www.curious-creature.com/category/android/page/2/):

> android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"

No such option exist in Recyclerview unfort. Is there a built in method to allow for these fading edges for recyclerview or will it just have to be a hack?

Answer (score 73, accepted):

I think the attribute you are looking for is:

```
android:requiresFadingEdge="horizontal|vertical"
```

you can search and better understand this attribute from the recycler view's [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/RecyclerView).

The other attribute you are talking about, `'cacheColorHint'`, can be used to match the fading color with that of your background. This attribute is the color upon which the list view is drawn, and is defined as an [opaque color](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.html#attr_android:cacheColorHint), because you don't always have a white background (which I think is the default color... but I'm not sure), the best option is to use a transparent color, "#00000000", as suggested by Romain Guy.

Hopefully this is what you are looking for!

Cheers

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thanks

Comment: I am not able to change the color of fade to show like a shadow, like the screenshot

Comment: don't use android:overScrollMode="never". it will never show over-scroll effects.

Comment: what about android:fadingEdge="vertical"?