# Fading edges in RecyclerView

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, recyclerview-layout

I have a RecyclerView in my app. It has straight sharpen edges, but I want to get faded edges when the list is bigger than the screen, that is, when there are so many items in the list that they don't fit in the screen and a scroll is generated.
I've tried some attributed on the XML of the layout but nothing works. The parent layout is ConstrainLayout.
Thanks.

Comment: There is no default behavior to do this on a RecyclerView. You'll need to put another View over top the bottom of the RecyclerView and give it a gradient from Clear to White (or whatever color you want to fade to). There are plenty of SO answers on how to make a gradient.

Answer (score 3):

You can use this:

```xml
android:requiresFadingEdge="horizontal|vertical"
```

You should see [this Stack Overflow post for more information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33720836/horizontal-recyclerview-with-fading-edges).

Comment: Yes, I tried it, but it was a mess. It relocated the edge on a strange way, and it hided half of the last item of the list(sorry I cannot upload a picture, I'm new). I read it has to do with the padding attribute. Do you know something about it?

Comment: @Raaaaac You cannot _embed_ a picture, but you can attach a link to the imgur picture, please do this or I will have no idea what you are talking about.