# Scroll bar gradient background and text

Tags: android, xml, layout, scrollview, gradient

i want to do the gradient of the image but i can't. I need some help please.

[image]

Comment: What you have tried so far ?

Comment: I solved @ADM with: `<ScrollView android:requiresFadingEdge="vertical">` and `android:fadingEdgeLength="150dp"`. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved!

`android:requiresFadingEdge="vertical"` and `android:fadingEdgeLength="150dp"`

On this link:

[making the edge of the scrollview fade when scrolling in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11538873/making-the-edge-of-the-scrollview-fade-when-scrolling-in-android)