# Fading on custom scrollview

Tags: java, android, scrollview

I created a custom scroll view that I use for various reasons.
I'm trying to apply a fading edge to it but I can't get it to work; it's working fine on standard scroll views.
This is how I use my custom scroll view:

```
<com.myapp.app.MyCustomScrollView
   android:id="@+id/myscustomscrollview"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:layout_margin="10dp">
   <LinearLayout...

   </LinearLayout>
</com.myapp.app.MyCustomScrollView>
```

I tried to add fading through the XML like this:

```
android:requiresFadingEdge="vertical"
android:fadingEdgeLength="5dp"
```

and it didn't work, so I tried by code:

```
myscustomscrollview.setHorizontalFadingEdgeEnabled(true);
myscustomscrollview.setFadingEdgeLength(FADING_SIZE);
```

and it didn't work either.

This is my custom view, I just extended Scrollview and overridden a method

```
public class MyCustomScrollView extends ScrollView {
    public MyCustomScrollView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public MyCustomScrollView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public MyCustomScrollView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent event) {
        //Custom logic
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please post the code of your custom view?

Comment: @joaquim-ley added

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16726054/4423647) and [this answer in](https://inneka.com/programming/android/making-the-edge-of-the-scrollview-fade-when-scrolling-in-android/)  innneka.com